# Download MP3 via file_get_contents when URL contains long dash (–)

Tags: php

I'm trying to download a set of MP3 files to a ZIP folder. All the MP3's are hosted on S3. My program works perfectly, except when the URL contains a long dash like this: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/publicverses/2Corinthians11verse24–33_user400_56.mp3`.

Notice the long dash between `24` and `33`. This file and others like it show up in the ZIP empty (i.e. 0kb). How can I fix this?

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
      $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
      $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $download_file);
  }
```

Comment: `urlencode` it possibly?

Comment: `–` is a non-ASCII character, which might be causing the problem. Try `urlencode()`

Comment: Where should I place the urlencode() function?

Comment: @jumpingmaniac `file_get_contents(urlencode($file))`. I am not quite sure, but try this.

Comment: That's what I thought. I tried that, but now ALL of my files are 0kb.

Comment: No, you can not just feed the whole URL to urlencode, that will encode characters such as `:` and `/` as well, and you'll end up with something totally unusable for an actual HTTP request. Start with `parse_url` to split it into its components, split the path at the `/`, encode the resulting parts individually ... and reassemble the whole thing. (Or encode the whole path in one go, and replace the resulting `%2f` back to / afterwards.)

Comment: Try this:
`$url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/publicverses/2Corinthians11verse24–33_user400_56.mp3';
$newURL = str_replace('–', urlencode('–'), $url); file_get_contents($newURL)`
Just encode the part that's causing the problem. It should work now

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the filename, or any part of the path, if it contains any high order characters like this unicode emdash. For the record, web browsers do this in the background for the sake of user convenience.

It would be easiest to do this *before* you construct the URL, but if you're stuck with a pre-formed URL with this problem then you need to break it apart and deal only with the pieces that you need to change. Eg:

```
// from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#106731
function unparse_url($parsed_url) {
  $scheme   = isset($parsed_url['scheme']) ? $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' : '';
  $host     = isset($parsed_url['host']) ? $parsed_url['host'] : '';
  $port     = isset($parsed_url['port']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['port'] : '';
  $user     = isset($parsed_url['user']) ? $parsed_url['user'] : '';
  $pass     = isset($parsed_url['pass']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['pass']  : '';
  $pass     = ($user || $pass) ? "$pass@" : '';
  $path     = isset($parsed_url['path']) ? $parsed_url['path'] : '';
  $query    = isset($parsed_url['query']) ? '?' . $parsed_url['query'] : '';
  $fragment = isset($parsed_url['fragment']) ? '#' . $parsed_url['fragment'] : '';
  return "$scheme$user$pass$host$port$path$query$fragment";
}

// this function assumes that *nothing* is encoded, otherwise it will
// double-encode the data and likely break it.
function url_encode_parts($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    // eg: UTF hostnames are encoded differently
    $parts['host'] = idn_to_ascii($parts['host']);
    $parts['path'] = implode('/', array_map('urlencode', explode('/', $parts['path'])));
    return unparse_url($parts);
}

$url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/publicverses/2Corinthians11verse24–33_user400_56.mp3';

var_dump(url_encode_parts($url));

// output:
// string(85) "https://s3.amazonaws.com/publicverses/2Corinthians11verse24%E2%80%9333_user400_56.mp3"
```

Ref:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone. In this case, I found that the simplest solution was to update my program such that all long dashes (`–`) are converted to regular dashes (`-`) in my URL structure. In other words, I decided to avoid special characters altogether rather than deal with the encoding issues.